# sorting a linked list with structures in C

Tags: c

I have tried using the method of bubble sorting i have learned in a program used to sort books that have been inserted into a linked list. Ive tried swapping the 2 nodes but that caused the nextptr to be swapped as well. i started this new function called authsort that is not referencing the members in the book structure. what would I need to change for this sort to work?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

struct book
{
    char author[30];
    char title[50];
    char hold2[50];
    char titleins[50];
    char genre[15];
    int rating;
    int comma;
    int titleshift;
    int number;
};
struct listnode
{
    struct book data;
    struct listnode *nextptr;
};
    typedef struct listnode LISTNODE;
    typedef LISTNODE *LISTNODEPTR;



    void insert(LISTNODEPTR *sptr, struct listnode data);
    void authsort(LISTNODEPTR sptr, struct listnode data);
    void freenodes(LISTNODEPTR currentptr);
    int add_2 (count, i, j, index, tag);
    void print_list(LISTNODEPTR, struct listnode book);
    int main ()
    {
        LISTNODEPTR startptr = NULL;
        struct listnode listnode;
        struct book book;
        int choice = 0;
        char item;
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int j = 0;
        char * pch2;
        char string[40];
        char string2[40];
        char * pch;
        int i = 0;
        while( choice != 2)
        {
        printf("What Would You Like To Do?\n");
        printf("1.Add Books\n2.exit\n3:sort by author\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        getchar();




    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
                printf("Enter your book title:");
                gets(listnode.data.title);
                for(i=0;i<100;i++)
                {
                    listnode.data.title[i] = tolower(listnode.data.title[i]);
                }
                printf("Enter the author:");
                if(listnode.data.title[0] == 't')
                    {
                        if(listnode.data.title[1] == 'h')
                        {
                            if(listnode.data.title[2] == 'e')
                            {
                                if(listnode.data.title[3] == ' ')
                                {
                                    book.titleshift = 4;
                                    pch = strtok(listnode.data.title, " ");
                                    strcpy(string, pch);
                                    pch2 = strtok(NULL, "");
                                    book.comma = strlen(pch2);
                                    strcpy(string2, pch2);
                                    strncat(string2, string, 20);
                                    strncpy(listnode.data.title, string2, 50);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                if(listnode.data.title[0] == 'a')
                {
                    if(listnode.data.title[1] == ' ')
                    {
                        book.titleshift = 2;
                        pch = strtok(listnode.data.title, " ");
                        strcpy(string, pch);
                        pch2 = strtok(NULL, "");
                        book.comma = strlen(pch2);
                        strcpy(string2, pch2);
                        strncat(string2, string, 20);
                        strncpy(listnode.data.title, string2, 50);
                    }
                }
                gets(listnode.data.author);
                for(i=0;i<100;i++)
                {
                    listnode.data.author[i] = tolower(listnode.data.author[i]);
                }
                printf("Enter the genre:");
                gets(listnode.data.genre);

                for(i=0;i<100;i++)
                {
                    listnode.data.genre[i] = tolower(listnode.data.genre[i]);
                }
                printf("Enter the quality:");
                scanf("%d", &listnode.data.rating);
                printf("Enter the number of pages:");
                scanf("%d", &listnode.data.number); // after scanning in from user, we insert and print the list
                insert(&startptr, listnode);
                print_list(startptr, listnode);
                break;
        case 2:
        freenodes(startptr);
        break;
        case 3:
        authsort(startptr, listnode);
        print_list(startptr, listnode);
        break;
    }
        }
    return 0;
}


/*********************************FUNCTION*********************************/
void print_list(LISTNODEPTR currentptr, struct listnode book)
{

    if (!currentptr)
        printf("List is empty.\n\n");
    else
     {
        printf("your list:\n");
         while (currentptr)

         {
             if(currentptr->data.comma > 1)
                {

             printf("%-15s %-20s %-15s %-15d %-15d\n", currentptr->data.author, currentptr->data.title, currentptr->data.genre, currentptr->data.rating, currentptr->data.number);
            currentptr = currentptr -> nextptr; // this will continue printing as long as there in a nextptr, or book

                }

                else if(currentptr->data.comma == 0)
                {
                    printf("%-15s %-20s %-15s %-15d %-15d\n", currentptr->data.author, currentptr->data.title, currentptr->data.genre, currentptr->data.rating, currentptr->data.number);
                    currentptr = currentptr -> nextptr; // this will continue printing as long as there in a nextptr, or book

                }
         }

        if(!currentptr)
        {
            printf("end of list\n\n");

        }
     }
}

/*********************FUNCTION******************/
void insert(LISTNODEPTR *sptr, struct listnode data)
{
     LISTNODEPTR newptr, previousptr, currentptr;
     newptr = malloc(sizeof(LISTNODE));
     int i = 0;

        if (newptr)
        {



            strcpy(newptr -> data.title,data.data.title);

            //if(book.titleshift == 0)
            //{

            //strcpy(newptr -> title,book.title);
            //}
            // here the books are being copied into the current node
            strcpy(newptr -> data.author, data.data.author);
            strcpy(newptr -> data.genre, data.data.genre);
            newptr -> data.rating= data.data.rating;
            newptr -> data.number= data.data.number;
            newptr -> nextptr = NULL;
            previousptr = NULL;
            currentptr = *sptr;

     while (currentptr != NULL && strcmp(data.data.title, currentptr -> data.title)>0)
                            // this compares the titles to insert by author
     {
        previousptr = currentptr;
        currentptr = currentptr -> nextptr;
     }
        if (previousptr == NULL)
        {
        newptr -> nextptr = *sptr;
        *sptr = newptr;
        }
        else
        {
            previousptr -> nextptr = newptr;
            newptr -> nextptr = currentptr;
        }
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Not inserted.\n");
            }
}

/*******************************FUNCTION***********************************/

/**************************FUNCTION*********************/
void freenodes(LISTNODEPTR currentptr)
{
 LISTNODEPTR tempptr;
 while(currentptr!=NULL)
 {
  tempptr=currentptr->nextptr;
  free(currentptr);
  currentptr=tempptr;
 }
}

void authsort(LISTNODEPTR sptr, struct listnode data)
{
    LISTNODEPTR nextptr;
    LISTNODEPTR previousptr;
    LISTNODEPTR currentptr;
    LISTNODEPTR tempptr;
    LISTNODEPTR trail;
        int count = 0;
        int j = 0;
        while(sptr != NULL)
        {
            count++;
            sptr = sptr -> nextptr;
        }
        for(j=0;j<count;j++)
        {

        currentptr = sptr;
        while(currentptr->nextptr != NULL)
        {


            if(strcmp(currentptr ->data.author, currentptr->nextptr.data.author)>0)
            {
                tempptr = currentptr ->nextptr;
                currentptr ->nextptr = currentptr ->nextptr->nextptr;
                currentptr ->nextptr = currentptr;


                if(currentptr == sptr)
                  sptr = trail = tempptr;
                else
                  trail->nextptr = tempptr;
                currentptr = tempptr;
              }

              trail = currentptr;
              currentptr = currentptr->nextptr;
        }

        }



}
```

Comment: the bubble sort that you learn in most books does not work on linked list. it is meant for array. If you wanna do sorting on linked list, the code will look very different. I would recommend you to take a look at recursive merge sort on linked list. it is rather short to implement.

Comment: go through this link http://geeksquiz.com/c-program-bubble-sort-linked-list/. This will help you.

Comment: @Mox: Why does bubble sort not work on linked lists? You exchange only adjacent nodes, which is easy to do. (I'm not saying it is a good sort, but it can be implemented for linked lists.)

Comment: @aa1992 thanks, i think mine is working now with that method.

Comment: @Oehm, oh yes u r right. i guess like the answer below has suggested. just swap the value instead of the reference.

Comment: @Mox: You can even swap the pointers, if you like. They are always adjacent, so that `a->next == b`.

Comment: After you have determined the count, (the only copy of) `sptr` is `NULL`.  use an auxiliary pointer of a separate function here.

Comment: @SergeiLevashov great to know that it helped you...happy coding

Answer (score 0):

See, your ultimate aim should be to have a linked list that is sorted. Now you are trying to sort two nodes, but you could even swap their data!

This involves no pointer relocation, and makes your program much easier to analyse and understand. I hope this hints you to get the right solution!

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:

- After you have determined the length, `sptr` is `NULL`. From here on, you can't do anything sensible with your code, because you have lost the head pointer.
- If you want to swap the nodes themselves and not only the data, you might have to update the head pointer. At the moment, you just pass the head pointer, but if the calling code must reflect the changes made to the head pointer, you should pass a pointer to the head pointer.
- When you swap the pointer, you must also update the pointer that points to the current node, which is either `sptr` or the `nextptr` member of the previous node.
- You use way too many temporary variables. The `trail` isn't ever used, for example, and neither is the second parameter to your function.

Let's fix these issues. First, we are not going to use acount. Instead, we keep track of whether we had to change any nodes on a pass. If not, we're done, because the list is sorted. Otherwise, we do another pass.

The issue of keeping track of the previous node has an elegant solution, which is related to passing a pointer to the head pointer as argument: Iterate with a pointer to the current node pointer, which adds one level of indirection: The iterating pointer `curr` now points to the pointer that points to the current node, which is either the original head pointer passed from your calling function or a `nextptr` member.

This solution does not make the head pointer a special case. It leads to shorter code, but also to a lot of noisy `(*curr)` syntax.

Here's a working implementation that swaps nodes instead of payload:

```
void authorsort(struct listnode **sptr)
{
    int done = 0;

    while (!done) {
        struct listnode **curr = sptr;

        done = 1;
        while ((*curr)->nextptr != NULL) {
            if (strcmp((*curr)->data.author, 
                (*curr)->next->data.author) > 0) {
                struct listnode *temp = (*curr)->nextptr;

                (*curr)->nextptr = temp->nextptr;
                temp->nextptr = *curr;
                *curr = temp;

                done = 0;
            }

            curr = &(*curr)->nextptr;
        }
    }
}
```

(Swapping the payload is easier, but swapping the nodes is necessary if you have pointers to these nodes from the outside, for example if a book collection refers to the books as pointers.)